# Space that vba does not "see" in word document??? What is that?

Tags: vba, ms-word, document, spaces

Words have several spaces between them:

[image: screenshot]

words have lots of spaces between them, but I can't replace those spaces using VBA with Regex (using chr(32) space(7), " ")

```
Sub SpacesR()
Dim MyRegEx As RegExp
Set MyRegEx = New RegExp
Dim txtDoc As Range
Set txtDoc = ActiveDocument.Range
With MyRegEx
.Pattern = Chr(32)
.Global = True
txtDoc.Text = .Replace(txtDoc.Text, "")
End With
End Sub
```

help me please!

These are the space symbols:

These are the space symbols:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you copy and paste the space symbol from your document into a comment here 
(The actual blank space looking character, not that circle symbol representation). Likely it's a non-breaking space, a unicode version of space that is commonly used in HTML and whatnot. You can pop what you copy into a text->hex converter to see the hex representation of the character which you can then cross reference to see what the name of the character at a site like https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/ascii-table-hex-to-ascii-value-character-code-chart-2/

Comment: Those are non-breaking spaces. You don’t need to complicate things by using RegEx to remove them. Word’s own Find and Replace will do the job much more quickly.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt 
I know, but it's that it makes several other replacements in my code stop working and these replacements, yes, you can't do it in a simple way. I created a button in word just to make several substitutions in a several texts and it would be a lot of work to do it manually.

Comment: `Find` is a method of the `Range` object and can also be used with wildcards to do most of what RegEx can do. If you don’t know how to use wildcards see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm If you don’t know how to use Find in VBA, record a macro to get you started.

Comment: @JNevill This is the space (        ), I don't know if you can copy it, or if your browser will interpret it as a common space. This is the link to the word document with that kind of space: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_YAaNqFspVD3UpBw_eiL_WSYw7zRJgQP/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113982472115334015649&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @TimothyRylatt 
Thank you! I understand now. I'm currently working on a solution with the macro recorder and it works and then it stops working. The way I found was to simply replace space, with space. Then he replaces the space copied from the internet with a common space. But I represent both types of space with a " ", since I don't know how to represent.

Comment: It's often a good idea to view your Word doc with invisible characters visible (`CRTL-*`). Helps figure things like that out

Comment: See https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/FindingSpecialCharacters.htm

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I've already done that and found that they are a very different type of space than usual. See the link in the second image of the question. If you want to take a look at the document, it's this one: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_YAaNqFspVD3UpBw_eiL_WSYw7zRJgQP/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113982472115334015649&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Timothy Rylatt is leading you on the correct track. The second image shows hard or non-breaking spaces.

Comment: That looks like a bunch of non-breaking spaces. Search for `^s`. A simple space will also work to find them.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you! It helped a lot, I even discovered here how to insert this type of space. To insert it, I press ctrl shift space or through the insert special characters symbol in word, on the insert tab.

Comment: Non-breaking space is `Chr(160)`

Comment: A little tip that has helped me a lot to identify such characters is to copy one to excel and then use the CODE function to identify which Chr type it is

Comment: @TimWilliams, Thank you! Really, I inserted it in excel to test, according to Boeryepes tip and that's it.